# Access mock session/object on the second function how? Unit-Testing Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, session, symfony, mocking

I have two function in a test file the first one will mock a session and the second one will use it is it possible? as of now every time i am going to access the session in the second function it's empty please badly need your help thanks...

**Test.php**

```
public function testCreate() {
    $session = createSession();
    var_dump($session->all());
}

/**
 * @depends testCreate
 */    
public function testDelete() {
    var_dump($session->all());
}
```

First Output:

```
["email"]=>
string(8) "sample@gmail.com"

["username"]=>
string(8) "samplesession"
```

Second Output:

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store mocked session outside method scope.
Do something like this:

```
...
protected $session;

public function testCreate() {
    $this->session = createSession();
    var_dump($this->session->all());
}

/**
* @depends testCreate
*/

public function testDelete() {
    var_dump($this->session->all());
}
...
```